# (SQL OR PYTHON) I would like to exclude all coordinates that are located in the Mediterranean sea

Tags: python, sql, folium

I have a set of coordinates in Egypt and some of these coordinates appear in the Mediterranean Sea when plotted in a map. There are many coordinates like this and I would have a difficult time removing them manually. So is there any way to do this by code either in SQL or by using Python.

Comment: How are your coordinates formatted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use geopandas for that, but you need the geometry for the mediterranean sea.

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Load location data into a GeoDataFrame
locations = gpd.read_file('location_data.shp')

# Load data for the Mediterranean Sea region into a GeoDataFrame
mediterranean_sea = gpd.read_file('mediterranean_sea_data.shp')

# Exclude all locations within the Mediterranean Sea region
locations_outside = locations[~locations.within(mediterranean_sea.geometry)]

# Save the resulting GeoDataFrame to a shapefile
locations_outside.to_file('locations_outside_mediterranean_sea.shp')
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't have the coordinates for the Mediterranean sea